# PHP couchbase integration just shows version number only in phpinfo()

Tags: php, couchbase, php-extension

I have tried to integrate couchbase in with PHP in a centOS 6.5 machine. And installed couchbase extension as they said in "http://www.couchbase.com/communities/php/getting-started". But I was not able to connect with the couchbase from PHP. When I checked my phpinfo() it just shows version number of couchbase extension only No configuration information showing there.

Answer (score 3):

Their example code no longer works and they need to update their site.  This is their original code:

```
<?php
// adjust these parameters to match your installation
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "", "default");
$cb->set("a", 101);
var_dump($cb->get("a"));
?>
```

To set-up a new data bucket, go to your site's address:
`http://127.0.0.1:8091/index.html`

Or type the following in the command line:

```
curl -X POST -d name=default -d ramQuotaMB=200 -d authType=none -d replicaNumber=2 -d proxyPort=11215 http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/buckets
```

Then you need to call `CouchbaseCluster` instead of `Couchbase` like this:

```
<?php
// adjust these parameters to match your installation
$cb = new CouchbaseCluster("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "");
$db = $cb->openBucket("default");
$db->upsert("a", array("value" => 10));
$var_a = $db->get("a");
var_dump($var_a->value);
?>
```

Your output should then look like this:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["value"]=> int(10) }
```

Comment: FYI - you are best off going through their set-up process instead of adding a bucket named "default".  If you manually add the "default" bucket above then you will not be able to complete Step 3 of 5 of their setup.  So visit the setup page for the DB (on your local site) and creating a bucket manually will not be required.

Comment: I have noticed very high error rates with their 2.0.0 PHP-SDK and I have downgraded it back to 1.2.2 so the original example will work and it runs very smoothly.  I'm expecting them to either fix or retract their 2.0.0 release very shortly after communicating with them this past week about these issues.